# Weyl groups are Coxeter groups proof

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, coxeter-groups, weyl-group, buildings

I'm reading part of a proof that says that Weyl groups of apartments of buildings are Coxeter groups.

Let $\Delta$ be a building and let $\Sigma$ be a fixed apartment of $\Delta$. Let $C$ be a fixed chamber of $\Sigma$ and let $S$ be the set of reflections of $\Sigma$ with respect to the walls of $C$. Then the Weyl group $W$ of $\Sigma$ is generated by $S$.

We have $s \in S$ and so $C$ and $sC$ are adjacent with common wall, say $B$. Let $\phi$ be the folding of $\Sigma$ that maps $sC$ to $C$. Then the action of $\phi$ and $s$ are identical on all chambers not in $\phi(\Sigma)$.

**My problem**

Next it says there are adjacent chambers $D$ and $D'$ with $D \not\in \phi(\Sigma)$ and $D' \in \phi(\Sigma).$ It then says that $\phi(D)=D'$ and this is the part I don't understand. I really cannot see where that comes from at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know anything else about the building, or about $D$ and $D'$?  For example, are $D$ and $D'$ adjacent to $\phi(\Sigma)$?  Is the building thick or thin?

Comment: All buildings in this book are assumed to be thick but the apartments are thin.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454745/weyl-groups-are-coxeter-groups-proof#comment1177168_454745), what is the book?  There is surely more information, because, exactly as written, this is false.

Comment: Suzuki - group theory I, theorem 4.7 page 346.

Comment: I don't have Suzuki in front of me, but...  As for the existence of $D$ and $D'$, we could take $D=sC$ and $D'=C$.  As for $\phi(D)=D'$ (for any $D$ and $D'$ with $D\not\in\phi(\Sigma)$ and $D'\in\phi(\Sigma)$):  The boundary of $\phi(\Sigma)$ as a subset of $\Sigma$ is equal to the set of points in $\Sigma$ fixed by $s$.  The common face of $D$ and $D'$ is on the boundary, so it is fixed by $s$, and we conclude that $sD=D'$.  Therefore also $\phi(D)=D'$.  Does that help?  Or am I assuming things that we don't know yet at that place in Suzuki?

Comment: They exist already because in the proof the chambers $D$ and $D'$ are chambers next to each other in a gallery. I understand that their common face is fixed by $s$ by I don't understand how this Implies that $\phi(D)=D'$ since this means that $\phi$ maps the vertex of $D$ that is not contained in $D \cap D'$ to the vertex of $D'$ that is not contained in $D \cap D'$. Why is this the case?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is a pure simplicial complex with the property that every codimension-1 face is contained in exactly two full-dimensional faces.  And $s$ is an automorphism of that complex.  So $s$ has to map $D$ to $D'$.  Thus also $\phi$ maps $D$ to $D'$.